# JavafxPorts - Android N

Tags: javafxports, gluon-mobile

I am trying to install and test my app on a Pixel C which is running Android N. The android monitor (in Intellij) is showing the Pixel C and is showing log output from the tablet.

However, when I try installing the app, I get an error:

Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to install on any devices.
        at org.javafxports.jfxmobile.plugin.android.task.Install.install(Install.groovy:58)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:227)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:585)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:568)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)

Any suggestions on how I can get my app installed and running on Android N? Do I have to downgrade my Pixel C to Android 6 to get the app to install?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to make sure it works as well on Android 5/6, have you tried the app in a different device before?

Comment: yes, the app works fine on Android 6.0.1. I ran the app on both my phone and the Pixel C when it was running 6.0.1. After I upgraded the Pixel C to Android N, I was no longer able to install the app.

Comment: Please contact: support at gluonhq dot com, in case you want to be a beta tester.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Android N is just a beta, JavaFXPorts doesn't provide support for it yet, but it is on the short-term roadmap.